# Adding missing references to Watson Unity SDK solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, ibm-watson

The only namespace reference present in my VS references is `IBM.Cloud.SDK` and the others are missing.

When I go to `Project` and then `Add references`, I can neither find them in the list nor in the SDK files.

How do I add these references?

**Another question**: What is the safest Unity version to integrate the IBM Watson Unity SDK and Core? Has anyone done this with no problems, that can guide me through it?

[image]

Comment: In VS open the Solution Explorer and look under References.  See if any are yellow.  Usually this happens when you upgrade Net Version and the upgrade process fails do to newer Net not containing same libraries as the original Net Version.   The solution is to delete the Yellow References from project and try to add the libraries again.  When a Net upgrade fails it stops so only some of the libraries get updated.  The upgrade usually stops on the first library that it cannot upgrade.  The csproj file contains the library and version of the library.  When version doesn't match you get errors.

Comment: There are no yellow ones. The ones that are there appear to be OK, for example `IBM.Cloud.SDK` but the missing ones that are underlined red in the code are missing, and when I try to add them, I cannot actually find them... BTW, I have upgraded the project packages, so it _probably_ doesn't have anything to do with out of date packages. These references are essentially `dll`s, right? Where should I look for them in the Watson `SDK` or `Core` packages?

Comment: Red ones indicate you are missing needed "using" statements at top of module.  Some libraries have more than one namespace.  The namespaces are the using statement at top of module.  So like with net library you have System.Net and System.Net.Socket.

Comment: The needed `using` statements are already in place. The libraries themselves are missing in the `References` drop-down of the Solution Explorer. I am trying to find out *where* to get them from and add them to the `References`!

Comment: You may be missing the license : https://ibm.github.io/dotnet-sdk-core/docs/v0.7.1/html/d6/d28/namespace_i_b_m_1_1_cloud_1_1_s_d_k_1_1_core.html